# Chkdsk all volumes without letter from powershell

Tags: powershell, foreach, volumes

This command listing all volumes.

```
GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume | FL -property  DeviceID
```

Output:

```
DeviceID : \\?\Volume{5ec9533e-e4e5-4d99-b8ea-a72673554361}\

DeviceID : \\?\Volume{c4dc8cf6-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\

DeviceID : \\?\Volume{e3ce6ce0-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\

DeviceID : \\?\Volume{0cc402b6-0000-0000-007e-000000000000}\

DeviceID : \\?\Volume{73773d2f-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\

DeviceID : \\?\Volume{c9f9eccc-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\

DeviceID : \\?\Volume{2bf2a75a-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\
```

I want to run chkdsk all volumes, so I added foreach after the command, but I cannot run chkdsk ?

```
GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume | FL -property  DeviceID | foreach  {Write-Host chkdsk FL -property  DeviceID /f}
```

Output

```
GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume | FL -property  DeviceID | foreach  {Write-Host chkdsk FL -property  DeviceID /f}
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
chkdsk FL -property DeviceID /f
```

What can I do for run chkdsk like this.

```
chkdsk "\\?\Volume{62f86aa7-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\" /f
```

Comment: `GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume | % { & chkdsk $_.DeviceID /f }`. Use the newer `Get-CimInstance` cmdlets. Also, the invocation operator `&` may not be needed in this case.

Comment: you command output is : `chkdsk \\?\Volume{0cc402b6-0000-0000-00ac-aba700000000}\ /f` , but I need `chkdsk "\\?\Volume{62f86aa7-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}\" /f`

Comment: `"$($_.DeviceID)"`

Comment: same result....

Comment: `GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume | % { & chkdsk "$($_.DeviceID)" /f }` didn't work? How about: `GWMI -namespace root\cimv2 -class win32_volume | % { iex "chkdsk '$($_.DeviceID)' /f" }`

Comment: nothing... The specified volume name does not have a mount point or drive letter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than use ChkDsk use the PowerShell replacement Repair-Volume cmdlet.

```
$Vols = Get-Volume

"There are $($Vols.Count) volumes to process!"

For ($Cntr = 0 ; $Cntr -lt $Vols.Count; $Cntr++) {
 
 Repair-Volume -ObjectId "$($Vols[$($Cntr)].ObjectId)"

}
```

Sample Results:

```
There are 7 volumes to process!
NoErrorsFound
Repair-Volume : Cannot open drive for direct access
Activity ID: {c776ba79-43f4-4dc7-82cd-2f61273ea4e3}
At G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Misc\Set-RepairVolumeOnAllVolumes.ps1:7 char:2
+  Repair-Volume -ObjectId "$($Vols[$($Cntr)].ObjectId)"
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...age/ 
   MSFT_Volume) [Repair-Volume], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 43013,Repair-Volume
 
NoErrorsFound
NoErrorsFound
NoErrorsFound
NoErrorsFound
NoErrorsFound
```

Here are the volumes on my machine:

```
PS> $vols

DriveLetter FriendlyName FileSystemType DriveType HealthStatus OperationalStatu
                                                               s               
----------- ------------ -------------- --------- ------------ ----------------
                         NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK              
D                        Unknown        CD-ROM    Healthy      Unknown         
H           Misc         NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK              
C           NVME         NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK              
                         NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK              
            ESP          FAT32          Fixed     Healthy      OK              
G           Data         NTFS           Fixed     Healthy      OK
```

You notice the error in the list that was for the D drive (CD/DVD w/no disc).
You can of course add more parameters to the command to suit your needs. You could also trap errors with a Try/Catch block.

Comment: its working thank you. Is it possible to show drive letter or drive number (disk30 or disk50) if have.

Comment: g770like I'm working on it. I've converted it to an advanced function and just putting the finishing touches on it. It now reports Drive Letters, Disk Numbers, and Partition Numbers along with some other information. I'll post it on my OneDrive Shared folder when I have it completed and fully tested as it's getting a bit long to post here. When it's finished I'll post a link here.

Comment: thank you. I am waiting

Comment: g770like, OK here's the link https://onedrive.live.com/embed?cid=50B4DFA90B96FF40&resid=50B4DFA90B96FF40%217603&authkey=AKzlqvMyQdAzoZ8  You'll find 2 programs in the zip file: Get-DriveStatusOnAllComputers.zip. One is the Advanced Function and the other is a demo program on calling it. There is also a file in the folder containing the zip that has the MD5 hashes for all the stuff in there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Get-DriveStatusOnAllComputers.zip, Get-RepairVolumeOnAllVolumes or Get-DriveStatusOnAllComputers are not working.

Comment: What error messages are you getting?

Comment: Get-RepairVolumeOnAllVolumes.ps1 > no output

Comment: Get-DriveStatusOnAllComputers > Get-RepairVolumeOnAllVolumes.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Chec
k the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\5900x-2\Desktop\Get-DriveStatusOnAllComputers.ps1:74 char:3
+ . G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Production\Get-RepairVolumeOnAllVolumes.ps1

    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (G:\BEKDocs\Scri...nAllVolumes.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: You need to modify Get-DriveStatusOnAllComputers.ps1 to point to the location where you placed Get-RepairVolumeOnAllVolumes.ps1 it's still point to the location on my computer. This is the line to change
#Dot sourcing function into the program
. G:\BEKDocs\Scripts\Production\Get-RepairVolumeOnAllVolumes.ps1

Comment: I edited, now result is Get-DriveStatusOnAllComputers >Unable to establish connection to: PC5

Unable to establish connection to: JanetsLaptop
Press any key to continue:

(note: PC5 is my computer name.)

Comment: Did you read the code at all? 2 lines down there is an array of computer names which you need to populate (as stated in the comment) with ONLY your computers!

Comment: I tried only my computer names. still same result.

Comment: Post your code somewhere online that I can get to it to take a look and post a link here.